# How to enable writethrough to persistent storage from Spark ignite RDD

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, ignite

JavaIgniteRDD is not storing the data in persistent storage MySQL.

I have configured 2 caches with MySQL as persistent storage.
One is updated from regular Ignite cache, other is updated though JavaIgniteRDD.savePairs.

In both the cases data is being updated in Ignite Cache.

But JavaIgniteRDD.savePairs is not persisting the data to MySQl. In-fact CacheStore write method itself not invoked.

Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `savePairs` with `overwrite=true`:

```
igniteRdd.savePairs(rdd, true)
```